# How to play an .m4a file in the browser? (React/HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-audio

I'm building a website that queries the iTunes API, and in the browser I need to be able to play the 30-second song previews associated with each song in the API (which are in .m4a format)

I've tried playing the file in both of the following ways, but neither worked:

```html
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src={track1} type="audio/m4a" />
</audio>

<video width="320" height="240">
    <source src={track1} type="video/mp4">
    </source>
</video>
```

When I tried using the audio tag, a media player appeared on the page, but it didn't actually load the file.

I've been researching this for a couple of hours but I haven't been able to find a way of accomplishing this (it doesn't seem like it should be this hard). Does anyone have any ideas of how I might make get this working? Thanks very much

Comment: Try taking out the `type` attribute maybe?

Comment: What codec are the m4a encoded with?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path of your sound files is correct? I was having this same issue on a React project.

Check the network tab in Dev tools to see what the status code is for your sound file resource. If it's 206 then it's most likely a file path issue:

[image: dev tools network tab]